# How can I force swf files to be run, not downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

For example, I want to make an iframe to this url: http://example.com/game.swf

The problem is, users who are on different browsers/devices/settings have the issue where instead of running the swf, the browser is just downloading it.

Keep in mind, I don't have access to the code for http://example.com, or the fla file. I need to use the iframe hack because of some issues with the swf.

Comment: Do any browsers even support SWF anymore? That may be the problem.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Lol, yeah. The issue does relate to that, though. By default, Chrome has a setting that makes you click to run a swf, but when linking directly to the file with this setting, it just downloads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe must load an HTML file, instead of directly loading some SWF file. So get around that rule by embedding SWF within the same html that the iFrame will be loading.

If `iframe` has code:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/game.html"> </iframe>
```

Then in game.html have code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="http://example.com/game.swf" width="800" height="600">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have access to the html of the iframe. Could I use the embed directly in my website?

Comment: @SamGurdus Yes. basically the browser must load an html page (even if that has Flash embedded). It's fine as long as the browser's own address bar isn't pointing to some direct link that ends with `.swf` (triggers auto-download).

Comment: Should I use object or embed?